# Restore MSSQL backup file

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, restore

I receive a file like this from my hosting provider when I downloaded the backup.The file had no extention and was inside a zip file. I want to read de data what is inside this backup or better yet throw all info in the tables if that's possble. I am afraid everything is gone, hopefully someone knows a way. I am using EntityFrameworkCore so the tables I have back using migration but it's the data that I need.

The file.

[image]

Comment: Why not talk to your hosting provider about the details of the file..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file seams to refer to `database_db.mdf` and `database_db_log.ldf`. Those info are generaly in `database_db.bak`files type. Try to add `.bak` extension to your file and the in an SQL SERVER instance, restore your `database_db` from this file.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think the file extension matters. That is, it can be restored without needing to have a '.bak' extension.

Comment: Extensions never matters for an app but in my opinion it's a good thing to keep all your files with a significative extension. Exemple with `txt` or `csv` files, the extension gives an idea on what's inside the file.